# Difference between docker machine with swarm options and running docker swarm init and join

Tags: docker, docker-machine, docker-swarm

I was trying to set up a cluster with docker swarm. However, I am a bit confused about how is docker-machine with swarm options different from initialising a swarm manager on one host and joining as workers from other hosts.

Here is an example for my question:

**docker-machine with swarm options**

```
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox --swarm --swarm-master --virtualbox-hostonly-cidr "10.0.0.1/24" node1
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox --swarm --swarm-discovery "token://..." --virtualbox-hostonly-cidr "10.0.0.1/24" node2
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox --swarm --swarm-discovery "token://..." --virtualbox-hostonly-cidr "10.0.0.1/24" node3
```

**join a manager node as worker nodes**

```
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox --virtualbox-hostonly-cidr "10.0.0.1/24" node1
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox --virtualbox-hostonly-cidr "10.0.0.1/24" node2
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox --virtualbox-hostonly-cidr "10.0.0.1/24" node3

eval $(docker-machine env node1)
docker swarm init

eval $(docker-machine env node2)
docker swarm join --token <token> <node1_IP>

eval $(docker-machine env node3)
docker swarm join --token <token> <node1_IP>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first method you used is from old docker version when SWARM need to have a discovery key/value store setup

```
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox --swarm --swarm-master --virtualbox-hostonly-cidr "10.0.0.1/24" node1
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox --swarm --swarm-discovery "token://..." --virtualbox-hostonly-cidr "10.0.0.1/24" node2
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox --swarm --swarm-discovery "token://..." --virtualbox-hostonly-cidr "10.0.0.1/24" node3
```

The second method you had used is the Swarm mode

> To use Docker in swarm mode, install Docker 1.12.0 or later

This was introduced in Docker 1.12.0. This is the method you should be using now as all new commands like `docker service`, `docker stack` require swarm mode. They won't work on the old one